# how to get to which album a photo belongs by facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using facebook graph api, I can retrieve an alubm obejct by sending a request to

graph.facebook.com/99394368305 (Coca-Cola fan page wall photos)

I can also retrieve a photo obejct by sending a request to
graph.facebook.com/98423808305 (A photo from the Coke fan page)

However the returned JSON string doesn't contain information which album the photo belongs to.

Is there any work around solution?

Answer (score 0):

my dear its simple solution is to query the photo table of facebook using FQL if you are having aid and pid.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/